# ListView content lost after fragment change

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I was trying to implement Dynamically updating a list in a ListFragment.
But, when i change my fragment(i.e. from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and back to fragment 1) the list contents are lost.

Below is my ListFragment.

```
public class FragmentOne extends ListFragment {

String[] order = new String[] {};

public FragmentOne(){}

/** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    /** Reference to the button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}}
```

Edited:

I was trying to implement a slider Menu, this is my activity (Im sorry the code is too long):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), true, "4"));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, "2"));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "4"));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "6"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), true, "8"));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "4"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    ListFragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FragmentOne();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new FragmentThree();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new FragmentFour();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new FragmentFive();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new FragmentSix();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code where you are switching the fragments?

Comment: You can store the state of the fragment in `onSaveInstanceState`. Refer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22505654/2868352

Answer (score 0):

When you go back from Fragment2 to Fragment1, you're creating a new instance of Fragment1. So of course your ListView will be empty (until the user adds items via the button you're supplying).

Maybe you need to modify `displayView(int position)` so it doesn't create an instance everytime, by null-checking and global vars maybe?

Answer (score 0):

as @lenix mentioned when you come back to fragment1 the displayView does create a new fragment because  you say that to the FragmentManager I've created new one and replace it..
In this case you should check isFragment added already? no then add otherwise hide and show fragment..

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(fragment1.isAdded){
        transaction.show(fragment1)
    }else{
        transaction.add(fragment1)
    }
```

dont forget to commit when you done.. and its just way to see you how you can do.. this snippet doesnt work..

Comment: I don't see a need for the boolean, he can simply null check.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you load your fragment, your ArrayList will start off empty. You could save the current list items to shared preferences and have the list fetched each time the fragment is loaded, or implement a set/get callback in your activity.