# Issue with dynamic Radiobutton in Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have set of two dynamic radiogroups in Fragment layout, when i slide the view from (right to left) or (left to right) the radiobutton changes on its own, not sure if it is issue with code or with xml layout. Any suggestions?

LayoutFragment.java

```
public class LayoutFragment extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;
    private String[] application = { "Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5", "Country6", "Country7", "Country8" };                     
    private String[] device = { "Country9", "Country10", "Country11", "Country12", "Country13", "Country14", "Country15", "Country16" }; 
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
    private RadioButton btn;
    private RadioButton btn2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    RadioButton button1;
    RadioButton button2;
    Button selectall;
    Context thiscontext;

    static LayoutFragment init(int val) {
        LayoutFragment truitonFrag = new LayoutFragment();
        // Supply val input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", val);
        truitonFrag.setArguments(args);
        return truitonFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        thiscontext = container.getContext();
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        Button myButton = (Button) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("");

                // Get selected radiobuttons
                if (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 1 : " + text1);
                }

                if (radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Button", "Text 2 : " + text2);
                }


                Toast.makeText(
                        thiscontext,
                        "Data Posting : APPLICATION : "
                                + text1 + " \nDEVICE : " + text2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


        //Draw Radiobuttons

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        for (int i = 0; i < application.length; i++) {
            button1 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button1.setId(i);
            button1.setText(application[i]);
            hourButtonLayout.addView(button1);

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup2,
                                int checkedId2) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup2.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup2.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup2.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn.getId() == checkedId2) {
                                    text1 = btn.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text1,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        ViewGroup hourButtonLayout2 = (ViewGroup) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.radio2); 
        for (int i = 0; i < device.length; i++) {
            button2 = new RadioButton(thiscontext);
            button2.setId(i);
            button2.setText(device[i]);
            hourButtonLayout2.addView(button2);

            radioGroup2
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup mRadioGroup,
                                int checkedId) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                btn2 = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                                int t = mRadioGroup.getId();
                                System.out.println(t);

                                if (btn2.getId() == checkedId) {
                                    text2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(thiscontext,
                                            "You selected : " + text2,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

        return layoutView;
    }

    public void onClear(View v){
        radioGroup1.clearCheck();
        radioGroup2.clearCheck();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Select Question1"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >
                </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:text="Select Question2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="560dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:checkedButton="@+id/sound">
                </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to set random id to each button

Comment: You are doing `mRadioGroup2.getChildCount()` where mRadioGroup2 is not yet set or visible. wh are you doing this ?

Comment: Try to debug the loop upon fragment visibility, it will give you the good idea of how Loops are initiated.

Comment: @Anil - Thanks, how can i do that?

Comment: `button1.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());` for example) instead of `button1.setId(i);`

Comment: @anil - Thanks, that worked. But what happens now is when I slide to next page the selected radiobuttons on first page gets unchecked

Comment: of course it will if you will not save its state) read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505327/android-save-restore-fragment-state or just google `how to save fragment state android`

Comment: @anil - Thanks a lot. Will do that

Comment: Not at all) hope you fix it)