# Android - Restore Fragment WebView state to avoid reload

Tags: android, html, android-fragments, android-webview, state

I have a bottom navigation bar app (created with an Android Studio template). The app navigates between two fragments. On one of the fragments, I have a WebView and I want to avoid it being reloaded each time I navigate to the fragment view.

After reading [this article](http://www.lucazanini.eu/en/2013/android/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-of-an-action-bar/), I've tried saving the webview state like so:

```
package com.example.bla.myapp.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.example.shlomishwartz.adintegration.R;

public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {
    private String PAGE_URL = "https://my.html.view.html";
    private Bundle webViewBundle;
    private WebView webView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View videoFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, null);

        webView = (WebView) videoFragment.findViewById(R.id.video_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO RESTORE THE STATE

        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            webView.loadUrl(PAGE_URL);
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
        return videoFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // HERE IS WHERE I SAVE THE STATE

        super.onPause();
        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }

}
```

However, each time I navigate to the fragment webViewBundle **is null** and the HTML is reloaded.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `Fragment`'s life cycle is strictly related to its `Activity`'s life cycle. `Fragment` methods like `onPause()` and `onResume()` only get called if `Activity`'s life cycle has switched to that states.

Have a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22505654/8555304), [fragment life cycle communications](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-1-fragments/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications.html#lifecycle) and [life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle) documentations.

**Edit**

1. First try adding your fragment to back stack.
2. Your `onPause()` method is probably useless at the moment unless when you change your activity while in your fragment.
3. Instead of trying restoring within `onCreateView` method, try to restore your state from instance variables within `onActivityCreated()` method.

**Edit-2**

Apparently the first part of this answer is not %100 correct. There may be some cases when fragment transaction occurs, methods like `onPause()` can get called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when debugging I can see the onPause method being called and webViewBundle being assigned, but when I check webViewBundle on the onCreateView it is null again.

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz Then, probably that fragment is destroyed. How about trying adding fragment to backstack?

Comment: Found it ... my issue was that I was creating a new Fragment each time I navigate

Answer (score 0):

only way to restore is to create view model .that too won't stop from getting reload .only the  WebView state will be restored.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).