# Android Fragment Back Stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, savestate, fragment-backstack

I have used multiple Fragments in my Project. I want to save a Fragment's state and restore this state when I come back to this. In this Fragment I show multiple images which change on button click. I use the following code for this:

```
String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
if (!fragmentPopped) {
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

It works fine & it saves state, but it does not show previous image's.

Any help, suggestion or tutorials would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15966777/1168654

Comment: why dont you use glide for images? it will save image in cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying with the fragment list ....

> Initilize the framents list

```
  static List<String> fragments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

> Code to fragment change and take in back stack

```
   String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //fragment not in back stack, create it.
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if(!fragments.contains(backStateName)) {

       // ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();

        fragments.add(backStateName);
        System.out.println("backStateName" + fragments);
    }
    else
    {


        ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
```

> onBackpressed

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(fragments.size()>0)
        {
            fragments.remove(fragments.size()-1);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

> for back remove stack

```
 final android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==0) {
               // dLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
               // dLayout.closeDrawers();

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.
It will not reload the fragment when you come back from previous fragment:

```
    if (!fragmentPopped) {
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_body));
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_body, fragment);
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container));
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Instead of

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used multiple fragments with this code.Put this code in your `MainActivity` where's your framelayout or fragment.

```
@Override    
public void onBackPressed() {
  /*  Fragment fragment = new SettingActivity();
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    // set the toolbar title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);*/
    //Log.e("title:", getTitle().toString());
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    //Log.e("title:", getTitle().toString());
    if (!getTitle().toString().equals("Home")) {

        Fragment fragment = new Activity_category();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
        this.setTitle("Home");
    } else {

        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save the images in the android disk cache when you open the fragment and display the images by reading from the disk cache it might resolve your problem. Follow the below link from google on how to save images in disk cache.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Below are the steps i think you should follow.

1. Store your images in the disk cache.
2. onAttaching your ImagesFragment to the Activity read the images from the disk cache and show them
3. when the fragment is popped from the backstack your code will automatically read the images from the disk cache.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You taking your fragment in back stack so its didn't fault of your fragment you need to check in your image library. May i know which library are you using. I recommended to use picasso library. I am also using this and getting state saved image in my fragment.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

You can do circular navigation by using below code. You can visit even two fragments as vice-versa by endless.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     hideLastFragment(fragmentTransaction);
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.profile_fragmentContainer, youfFragment, fragmentTagName).addToBackStack(fragmentTagName);
     fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    /**
         * To hide the last fragment
         *
         * @param fragmentTransaction FragmentTransaction
         */
        public void hideLastFragment(FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            final int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
            if (backStackCount >= 0) {
                String fragmentName = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(backStackCount).getName();
                Fragment lastFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
                fragmentTransaction.hide(lastFragment);
            }
        }
```